# When does $PATH get consulted in shell usage?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Sometimes, I have to specify a full path, because $PATH is seemingly not consulted:

```
####            I have `virtualenv` and it's on my path            ####

$ virtualenv --version      # `virtualenv` is on my path
1.7.1.2
$ which virtualenv          # further details
/usr/bin/virtualenv
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

####               However, I can't `stat virtualenv`:             ####

$ stat virtualenv
stat: cannot stat `virtualenv': No such file or directory

####              I have to use `stat `which $BINARY``               ####

$ stat `which virtualenv`
  File: `/usr/bin/virtualenv'
  Size: 54              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 22860       Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2012-11-28 23:48:03.919400541 -0500
Modify: 2012-04-23 06:34:09.000000000 -0400
Change: 2012-11-28 17:24:31.335400569 -0500
 Birth: -
$
```

Why do I have to use `which virtualenv` if it's on my path?

Comment: I get the same results as you on my box. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer as to why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$PATH` is only consulted when **executing** commands. When the shell has to search for a command to execute, it consults `$PATH` and walks down the list of directories in `$PATH` and picks the first executable file (with an appropriate execute bit set in the permissions) matching the supplied name, and executes it.

When you run `stat virtualenv`, you are passing `virtualenv` as an argument to the `stat` program. Assuming that `stat` is written in C, it then sees `virtualenv` as an argument in the program's main method:

`int main(int argc, char** argv)`

The `argv` contains two elements: index 0 is the command you used to invoke the program itself, so it's "stat". index 1 is the first command line argument, so it's "virtualenv".

This happens because the `exec()` series of system calls (look up the manpage if you're curious) allow you to pass an array of command line arguments when you replace the current process with a child process. The shell does call some variant of `exec()` and it parses your command line to determine which command line argument array to pass as `argv`.

Since `stat` doesn't know whether the file you supplied is a normal file, symlink, hardlink, executable or not, directory, etc., it doesn't search `$PATH` to find it. It treats the passed-in argument as specifying, specifically, `${PWD}/virtualenv` where `${PWD}` is expanded to the current working directory at the time that the `stat` program was invoked. This is called a **relative path**.

Almost all commands that accept relative paths for file names as an argument will **not** search `$PATH`, although a few commands might do so, such as `bash` or `ssh` if you tell them to execute a command in the child shell environment. There is nothing preventing any arbitrary command from looking through any particular environment variable for the file you supply, but it's application-specific behavior. It wouldn't make any sense at all to search `$PATH` for relative paths, because `$PATH` is only for executable files.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for incorporating the C and system call execution narrative.

Answer (score 3):

The `PATH` is needed and consulted when you are trying to execute something.

Unlike Windows, on Unix you always need to specify executable files with a path. `./foo.bin` or `/usr/bin/foo.bin`.  However for simplicity there exists this thing called `PATH`.  So it suffices to type `foo.bin` because `/usr/bin` happens to be in your path.

And if you ever wonder *which* file is resolved via `foo.bin`, `which` is there to tell you: `/usr/bin/foo.bin`.

Therefore every other UNIX tool accepting both executable and non-executable files as arguments, will probably not consult `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The PATH is consulted by the shell when executing programs to find the program to execute. When it's a parameter (such as to the `which` or `stat` commands in your example), the shell just passes it to the program that it found as it, and the program decides what to do with it.

The `which` command is built into bash, and it takes the argument and consults the shell's path to figure out what the shell would do to execute it. Most other programs (including most other programs built into bash), such as `stat` in your example, just use the path and try to find it in the current directory in the filesystem.

So, executing commands (and things like `which` which are trying to figure out what commands to execute) are the only things that use the PATH.